# Drawing unstructured grids with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am extremely new to Tikz, and know that it's easy to draw regular (Cartesian) grids, but haven't seen any examples using unstructured grids.

Is this possible to do in Tikz, and if so, is there a MWE available somewhere?

EDIT: From the comments below, to better clarify what I'm looking for:

To start, I would like a 2D case with a small mesh, say regularly spaced nodes (5x5) made into a Delaunay mesh. I would only need to display vertices and edges.

Eventually, I'd like to expand the example to 3D and overly semi-transparent block elements on this mesh, elements similar to the cone segment on the left of this example: texample.net/tikz/examples/3d-cone

My case would be a bit simpler since I'd just be using cubes. However, I just want to get the 2D mesh case figured out first, and expand from there.

EDIT2: Based on the answer below, I drew a grid with regular spacing using:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\ii=int(\i-1);}] in {0,...,3}{
  \foreach \j [evaluate={\jj=int(\j-1);}] in {0,...,3}{
    \coordinate [shift={(\j,\i)}] (n-\i-\j) at (0:0);
\ifnum\i>0
  \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ii-\j);
\fi
\ifnum\j>0
  \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\i-\jj);
  \ifnum\i>0
    \pgfmathparse{int(rnd>.5)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
      \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ii-\jj);
    \else%
      \draw [help lines] (n-\ii-\j) -- (n-\i-\jj);
    \fi%
  \fi
\fi
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

With the only issue that the way it connects the vertices is not always consistent.

Comment: What do you mean with "unstructured grids"?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Sorry, that was a little domain specific. In my field, an "unstructured grid" is a way to tessellate a plane, most often using triangles, It is often done using Delaunay triangulation, but there are other ways of constructing the grid..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\ii=int(\i-1);}] in {0,...,11}{
  \foreach \j [evaluate={\jj=int(\j-1);}] in {0,...,11}{
    \coordinate [shift={(\j,\i)}] (n-\i-\j) at (rand*180:1/4+rnd/8);
\ifnum\i>0
  \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ii-\j);
\fi
\ifnum\j>0
  \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\i-\jj);
\fi
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And some triangles...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\ii=int(\i-1);}] in {0,...,7}{
  \foreach \j [evaluate={\jj=int(\j-1);}] in {0,...,7}{
    \coordinate [shift={(\j,\i)}] (n-\i-\j) at (rand*180:1/4+rnd/8);
\ifnum\i>0
  \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ii-\j);
\fi
\ifnum\j>0
  \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\i-\jj);
  \ifnum\i>0
    \pgfmathparse{int(rnd>.5)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
      \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ii-\jj);
    \else%
      \draw [help lines] (n-\ii-\j) -- (n-\i-\jj);
    \fi%
  \fi
\fi
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Although something like `asymptote` may be better for this kind of thing (see [g.kov](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260683/23215)'s answer), if you like `python` and use `scipy` and are happy compiling with `--shell-escape` the following (rather impractical) code may be a useful starting point.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
{\obeyspaces\obeylines%
\gdef\delauney#1#2{%
\immediate\write18{echo "x y" > #1_points.dat; echo "%
import numpy as np
points=np.array([#2])
for point in points:
    print point[0], point[1]
" | python >> #1_points.dat}%   
\immediate\write18{echo "p1 p2 p3" > #1_triangles.dat; echo "%
import scipy.spatial as sp
import os
import numpy as np
points=np.array([#2])
triangulation=sp.Delaunay(points)
for simplex in triangulation.simplices:
    print
    for vertex in simplex:
        print vertex,
" | python >> #1_triangles.dat}%   
}}

\begin{document}
\def\points{(0,0)}
\foreach \i in {1,...,50}{
  \pgfmathparse{rand*10cm}\let\x=\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathparse{rand*10cm}\let\y=\pgfmathresult
  \xdef\points{\points,(\x,\y)}%
}
\delauney{d1}{\points} 

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[width=10cm, height=10cm, axis lines=none]
\addplot [patch, patch refines=0, mesh, help lines,
  patch table={d1_triangles.dat}] table {d1_points.dat}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for. Is there any way to force triangulation (like Delaunay)? That may be beyond the abilities of Tikz, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @chasely Proper Delauney triangulation is going to to be really _hard_ in TikZ, but it is possible to get a sort of triangular irregular grid.

Comment: Thanks, I don't need proper Delauney triangulation (though that would be nice). The example you provided is very good to get me started.

Comment: @chasely: I had some success using lualatex but it is slow (and I am not used to lua). Your best bet probably is to create the mesh with an external application and to import it into Tikz/LaTeX in a table like format. However, we probably need more detail. What do you want to display? Only edges and vertices? Color coded faces? 2D 3D?

Comment: @Nobody To start, I would like a 2D case with a small mesh, say regularly spaced nodes (5x5) made into a Delaunay mesh. I would only need to display vertices and nodes.

Eventually, I'd like to expand the example to 3D and overly semi-transparent block elements on this mesh, elements similar to the cone segment on the left of this example: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/3d-cone/ My case would be a bit simpler since I'd just be using cubes.

However, I just want to get the 2D mesh case figured out first, and expand from there.

Comment: @chasely: You should put the contents of that comment into your question so it is not buried in these comments. Also, by `vertices and nodes` you mean `vertices and edges`, right? At least for me, vertex and node signify the same object within a graph.

Comment: @Nobody Sorry for the confusion, I did mean vertices and edges. I also appended my comment to my original question.

Answer (score 10):

A interpretation of an "unstructured grid" with random lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\xmin{0}
    \def\xmax{5}
    \def\ymin{0}
    \def\ymax{5}
    \def\xnum{20}% number of horizontal lines
    \def\ynum{20}% number of vertical lines
    \pgfmathsetseed{1000}% initialize randomness for reproducable results
    \draw[help lines]
      \foreach \i in {1, ..., \ynum} {
        (\xmin, {\ymin + rnd*(\ymax - \ymin)})
        -- ++(\xmax - \xmin, 0)
      }
      \foreach \i in {1, ..., \xnum} {
        ({\xmin + rnd*(\xmax - \xmin)}, \ymin)
        -- ++(0, \ymax - \ymin)
      }
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 10):

Since you've asked,  "`Asymptote` uses a robust version 
of Paul Bourke’s Delaunay triangulation algorithm 
based on the public-domain 
exact arithmetic predicates written by Jonathan Shewchuk" (from the docs).

Here is an example with the circles added:

```
//  d.asy :
//    
settings.outformat="pdf";
import graph;
size(8cm);
pen p=deepblue+0.4bp;
pen[] circPen={red,deepgreen,blue};
int np=12;
pair[] points;
real r() {return unitrand();}
pair circCenter(pair A,pair B,pair C,real eps=1e-8){
  pair O,P,Q;
  real d;
  P=A-B;
  Q=B-C;
  d=P.x*Q.y-P.y*Q.x;
  assert(abs(d)>eps,"Collinear points");
  O=( (B.y-C.y)*(A.x^2-B.x^2+A.y^2-B.y^2)+(B.y-A.y)*(B.x^2-C.x^2+B.y^2-C.y^2)
      ,
      (C.x-B.x)*(A.x^2-B.x^2+A.y^2-B.y^2)+(A.x-B.x)*(B.x^2-C.x^2+B.y^2-C.y^2)
    )/(2*d);
  return O;
}

srand(123);
for(int i=0; i < np; ++i) points.push((r(),r()));
int[][] trn=triangulate(points);
pair O, t[];
for(int i=0; i < trn.length; ++i) {
  t=points[trn[i]];
  O=circCenter(t[0],t[1],t[2]);
  draw(t[0]--t[1]--t[2]--cycle,p);
  draw(Circle(O,abs(O-t[0])),circPen[i%circPen.length]+0.5bp+ opacity(0.8));
}
for(int i=0; i < np; ++i) dot(points[i],p+0.6bp,UnFill);
clip(box((0,0),(1,1)));
//
// To get d.pdf, run as:
//    
// asy d.asy
//
```

[image]