# Adding 3D elements to a grid in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles

Based on [my question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260610/drawing-unstructured-grids-with-tikz/) I created the the triangular mesh given below. Note that I am very new to Tikz so I don't know if this is the best approach.

I would like to add 2 to 3 3D elements to the grid, basically placing cubes (of different sizes) on top of the grid with an isometric view so **both** the grid and cubes are in isometric view (so the grid [displays similar to one segment of this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/swan-wave-model/). It is important that the vertices of the cube **don't intersect** with the vertices or edges of the already-created mesh.

Then I would like to add the x-y coordinates of the cubes to a mesh, creating a separate plot *above* the one with the cubes, showing a 2D "plan" view of the domain.

Stylistically, I like the cone on the left side in [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/3d-cone/), but I'm not sure how to recreate something similar with cubes in Tikz.

Is this possible, and is there a MWE available somewhere?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\ii=int(\i-1);}] in {0,...,2}{
  \foreach \j [evaluate={\jj=int(\j-1);}] in {0,...,2}{
    \coordinate [shift={(\j,\i)}] (n-\i-\j) at (0:1);
\ifnum\i>0
  \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ii-\j);
\fi
\ifnum\j>0
  \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\i-\jj);
  \ifnum\i>0
    \pgfmathparse{int(rnd>.5)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
      \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ii-\jj);
    \else%
      \draw [help lines] (n-\ii-\j) -- (n-\i-\jj);
    \fi%
  \fi
\fi
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Triangular mesh created with Tikz]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

Here's another option producing an isometric view; the squares in the top layer can be easily labelled since the four corners can be accessed using `(t-#)`, `(l-#)`, `(b-#)`, and `(r-#)` (see code below):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}

\def\Side{0.5cm}
\newcounter{mycube}

\tikzset{  
  cube/.style={
    thin,
    fill opacity=.5,
    fill=cyan!40,
    line join=round
    }
}

\newcommand\Cube[1][1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1]
  \filldraw[cube] 
    (0,0) -- 
    ++(30:\Side) coordinate (lr) -- 
    ++(0,\Side) -- 
    ++(210:\Side) -- 
    cycle --
    ++(150:\Side) -- 
    ++(0,\Side) -- 
    ++(-30:\Side) -- 
    cycle;
  \filldraw[cube] 
    (0,\Side) -- 
    ++(30:\Side) -- 
    ++(150:\Side) coordinate (up) -- 
    ++(210:\Side) -- 
    cycle;
  \draw[dashed,help lines]
    (up) -- (0,\Side);  
  \draw[dashed,help lines]
    (lr) -- ++(150:\Side) -- ++(210:\Side);  
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand\BorderCube[1][1]{%
\stepcounter{mycube}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1,remember picture]
  \filldraw[cube] 
    (0,0) coordinate (b-\themycube) -- 
    ++(30:\Side) coordinate (r-\themycube) -- 
    ++(150:\Side) coordinate (t-\themycube) -- 
    ++(210:\Side) coordinate (l-\themycube) -- 
    cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newsavebox\myboxa
\newsavebox\myboxb
\newsavebox\myboxc
\savebox\myboxa{\Cube[0.5]}
\savebox\myboxb{\Cube[0.75]}
\savebox\myboxc{\Cube[0.35]}

\newsavebox\myboxd
\newsavebox\myboxe
\newsavebox\myboxf
\savebox\myboxd{\BorderCube[0.5]}
\savebox\myboxe{\BorderCube[0.75]}
\savebox\myboxf{\BorderCube[0.35]}

\newcommand\MyGrid{
\pgfmathsetseed{9}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\ii=int(\i-1);}] in {0,...,2}{
  \foreach \j [evaluate={\jj=int(\j-1);}] in {0,...,2}{
    \coordinate [shift={(\j,\i)}] (n-\i-\j) at (0:1);
\ifnum\i>0
  \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ii-\j);
\fi
\ifnum\j>0
  \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\i-\jj);
  \ifnum\i>0
    \pgfmathparse{int(rnd>.5)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
      \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ii-\jj);
    \else%
      \draw [help lines] (n-\ii-\j) -- (n-\i-\jj);
    \fi%
  \fi
\fi
}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,
  y={(-1cm,0.5cm)},
  x={(1cm,0.5cm)}, 
  z={(0cm,1cm)}
]
\MyGrid
\node[overlay] at (1.65,1.35) {\usebox\myboxa};
\node[overlay] at (1.7,0.5) {\usebox\myboxb};
\node[overlay] at (2.7,1.35) {\usebox\myboxc};
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,50pt)}]
\MyGrid
\node[overlay] at (1.65,1.35) {\usebox\myboxd};
\node[overlay] at (1.7,0.5) {\usebox\myboxe};
\node[overlay] at (2.7,1.35) {\usebox\myboxf};

\node[above=-2pt,font=\tiny] at (t-2) {$a$};
\node[left=-2pt,font=\tiny] at (l-2) {$b$};
\node[below=-2pt,font=\tiny] at (b-2) {$c$};
\node[right=-2pt,font=\tiny] at (r-2) {$d$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### First version

You can use the [`tikz-3dplot`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-3dplot) package:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\newcommand\Cube[1][0.1]{%
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=#1,
  tdplot_main_coords,  
  cube/.style={thin,fill opacity=.5,fill=cyan!40,line join=round}
]
  %draw the bottom of the cube
  \filldraw[cube] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,0,0) -- cycle;
  %draw the back-right of the cube
  \filldraw[cube] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) -- (0,2,2) -- (0,0,2) -- cycle;
  %draw the back-left of the cube
  %\filldraw[cube] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) -- (2,0,2) -- (0,0,2) -- cycle;
  %draw the front-right of the cube
  \filldraw[cube] (2,0,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,2,2) -- (2,0,2) -- cycle;
  %draw the front-left of the cube
  \filldraw[cube] (0,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,2,2) -- (0,2,2) -- cycle;
  %draw the top of the cube
  \filldraw[cube] (0,0,2) -- (0,2,2) -- (2,2,2) -- (2,0,2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand\BorderCube[1][0.1]{%
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=#1,
  tdplot_main_coords,  
  cube/.style={thin,fill opacity=.5,fill=cyan!40,line join=round}
]
  %draw the bottom of the cube
  \filldraw[cube] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,0,0) -- cycle;
  %draw/hide the top of the cube
  \filldraw[opacity=0] (0,0,2) -- (0,2,2) -- (2,2,2) -- (2,0,2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newsavebox\myboxa
\newsavebox\myboxb
\newsavebox\myboxc
\savebox\myboxa{\Cube}
\savebox\myboxb{\Cube[0.15]}
\savebox\myboxc{\Cube[0.075]}

\newsavebox\myboxd
\newsavebox\myboxe
\newsavebox\myboxf
\savebox\myboxd{\BorderCube}
\savebox\myboxe{\BorderCube[0.15]}
\savebox\myboxf{\BorderCube[0.075]}

\newcommand\MyGrid{
\pgfmathsetseed{3}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\ii=int(\i-1);}] in {0,...,2}{
  \foreach \j [evaluate={\jj=int(\j-1);}] in {0,...,2}{
    \coordinate [shift={(\j,\i)}] (n-\i-\j) at (0:1);
\ifnum\i>0
  \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ii-\j);
\fi
\ifnum\j>0
  \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\i-\jj);
  \ifnum\i>0
    \pgfmathparse{int(rnd>.5)}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
      \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ii-\jj);
    \else%
      \draw [help lines] (n-\ii-\j) -- (n-\i-\jj);
    \fi%
  \fi
\fi
}}
}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{60}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  tdplot_main_coords,
  cube/.style={very thick,black},
]
\MyGrid
\node[overlay] at (1.15,0.55) {\usebox\myboxa};
\node[overlay] at (2.35,0.28) {\usebox\myboxb};
\node[overlay] at (2.25,1.15) {\usebox\myboxc};
\begin{scope}[shift={(0,50pt)},transform shape]
\MyGrid
%\begin{scope}[shift={(0pt,0pt)}]
\node[overlay] at (1.15,0.55) {\usebox\myboxd};
\node[overlay] at (2.35,0.28) {\usebox\myboxe};
\node[overlay] at (2.25,1.15) {\usebox\myboxf};
%\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cubes don't look in isometric view, do they ?

Comment: @Tarass I have no idea what that is.

Comment: @Tarass perhaps what I just did in my edit?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I updated my question; I would like the grid to be in isometric view as well.

Comment: @chasely I updated my answer. Is it somethink like this what you have in mind?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, that's what I was looking for. 

Is there a way to add a plot above that has the grid and add points for the x-y coordinates of the vertices of the cubes? I tried using the `scope` environment, but it produced errors.

Comment: @chasely Sure is possible, but why don't you ask all your requirements from the beginning? It's not nice to have to rewrite the answer each time you add a requirement.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I apologize. I will do so in the future. Thank you for your help. I've clarified the original question to add this feature in case you or anyone else is willing to tackle it.

Comment: @chasely Should this new grid also be in isometric view?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Yes, it should also be in isometric view.

Comment: @chasely Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @chasely You're welcome. I updated the answer and corrected a little problem.

Comment: @chasely I updated my answer with a completely new approach: It's simpler (in my opinion) and now you can easily place labels in the squares in the top layer.

Comment: @chasely I forgot the restriction about intersections; tomorrow I'll fix this.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you for your willingness to do so, but it is not necessary. It is a requirement that can be taken care of manually by adjusting the scale/location of the cubes.