# small colorful rectangles filling one page

Tags: xetex, pdftex, color, rules

Would it be difficult in LaTeX to generate one full A4 page of small
rectangles of size say 2x3mm in **colors** in the form

```
\smallbox{step red}{step green}{step blue}{size x}{size y}
```

where step is some small number like 0.05 (or appropriate size) ranging from 0 to 1 and 
e.g. "step red" means that that amount of the red color be present? So

```
\smallbox{1}{0}{0}{2mm}{3mm}
```

should be 2x3mm red rectangle ?

**EDIT** I've now got an almost working example :
just plug-in colors and distirbute `\n` over 3 values as in
`\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{219, 48, 122}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{cmd}{gray}{0.6}
\newcounter{mm}
\setcounter{mm}{0}
\begin{document}
  \foreach \n in {1,...,80} {\addtocounter{mm}{1} \themm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not especially difficult, no.

Comment: @cfr what I can do is one rectangle using \hrule with a definite color, like blue.

Comment: Then show us what you have done so far.

Comment: You can look at `xcolor` for information about colour series.

Comment: @AlexG Please see my **EDIT**.

Comment: See my answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315047/ for an example with colour series. Though I just took that from the manual, I think.

Comment: @user2925716: So how should the colours change as you're moving left-to-right / top-to-bottom on the page? Should one cycle through the red colours, nested within the blue colours, nested within the green colours? Or just step through them all of once, linearly, from 0,0,0 through to 255,255,255?

Comment: @Werner 3 nested loops would be OK. I'm not used to LaTeX programming which is a bit confusing to me. I've posted as much as I could for the moment.But I think few little step are missing and it will be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,xcolor,pgffor}
\geometry{scale=1}
\definecolorseries{mycolours}{rgb}{last}[rgb]{1,1,1}[rgb]{1,0,0}
\resetcolorseries[98]{mycolours}
\begin{document}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \noindent\foreach \n in {1,...,98} {\color{mycolours!!+}\rule{30mm}{20mm}\hskip1pt}
\end{document}
```

[image: white to red "boxes"]

```
\geometry{scale=1}
```

This is just setting the page margins etc. to zero for demonstration purposes i.e. so I can use the whole paper for the coloured rules.

```
\definecolorseries{mycolours}{rgb}{last}[rgb]{1,1,1}[rgb]{1,0,0}
```

This defines a colour series `mycolours` using the colour model `rgb`, method `last`, 'base' (starting colour) `[rgb]{1,1,1}` and 'step' (final colour in this case) `[rgb]{1,0,0]`. Note this isn't the actual 'step', but the basis for calculating it according to method `last`.

```
\resetcolorseries[98]{mycolours}
```

This calculates the 'step' between colours in the series, given that the series is to have `98` colours.

```
  \noindent\foreach \n in {1,...,98} {\color{mycolours!!+}\rule{30mm}{20mm}\hskip1pt}
```

`\color{mycolours!!+}` selects the current colour from series `mycolours` and then increments the index so that on the next call, the next colour in the series will be used.

For further explanation, `texdoc xcolor` can provide all the gory details of colour series, including the algorithms used to calculate the 'step' for each 'method' and the interpretation of the arguments passed to `\definecolorseries` in each case. It also has lots of examples of colour series and information about calling the colours etc.

Or

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,xcolor,pgffor}
\geometry{scale=1}
\definecolorseries{myreds}{rgb}{last}[rgb]{1,1,1}[rgb]{1,0,0}
\resetcolorseries[32]{myreds}
\definecolorseries{myblues}{rgb}{last}[rgb]{1,1,1}[rgb]{0,0,1}
\resetcolorseries[32]{myblues}
\definecolorseries{mygreens}{rgb}{last}[rgb]{1,1,1}[rgb]{0,1,0}
\resetcolorseries[32]{mygreens}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \noindent\foreach \n in {1,...,32} {\foreach \i in {myreds,myblues,mygreens}{\color{\i!!+}\rule{30mm}{20mm}\hskip1pt}}
\end{document}
```

[image: white to red/green/blue "boxes"]

`\definecolorseries` and `\resetcolorseries` are doing the same in this example as in the earlier one, but I'm putting `32` colours into each of 3 series, rather than `98` into just 1. Note that the key word `last` in all 4 uses of `\definecolorseries` tells you the 'method' used to calculate the 'step' is the same in each case.

Comment: That's completely OK. I just need to understand what does this `\noindent\foreach \n in {1,...,98} {\color{mycolours!!+}\rule{30mm}{20mm}\hskip1pt}` esepecially `\color{mycolours!!+}` ?

Comment: I can see now. I don't think I would ever come out with this solution on my own. And what about these commands : `\geometry{scale=1}
\definecolorseries{myreds}{rgb}{last}[rgb]{1,1,1}[rgb]{1,0,0}
\resetcolorseries[32]{myreds}` ?

Comment: @user2925716 I've added some explanation into the answer.