# How to draw unstructured grid with labels with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-arrows

I want to draw a figure in Tikz similar to the following picture

[image]

I have tried using the code from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/260610/drawing-unstructured-grids-with-tikz) so I have the following MWE

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i [evaluate={\ii=int(\i-1);}] in {0,...,5}{
        \foreach \j [evaluate={\jj=int(\j-1);}] in {0,...,9}{
            \coordinate [shift={(\j,\i)}] (n-\i-\j) at (rand*180:1/4+rnd/8);
            \ifnum\i>0
            \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ii-\j);
            \fi
            \ifnum\j>0
            \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\i-\jj);
            \fi
    }}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code gives the following ouput

[image]

The problem here is that I don't have those black nodes of which I don't know how to place them on every intersection. Also, I don't know how I can place the tiny squares and the text locating nodes. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nodes are all given in the code, and already named, so we only have to switch from coordinate to some circle shaped node that we fill. Even the counters needed for the barycenters are provided.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\ii=int(\i-1);}] in {0,...,5}{
    \foreach \j [evaluate={\jj=int(\j-1);}] in {0,...,9}{
        \node [shift={(\j,\i)},circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] (n-\i-\j) at
        (rand*180:1/4+rnd/8){};
        \ifnum\i>0
         \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ii-\j);
         \ifnum\j>0
          \node[draw,inner sep=1.5pt] at 
            (barycentric cs:n-\i-\j=1,n-\ii-\j=1,n-\i-\jj=1,n-\ii-\jj=1){};
         \fi
       \fi
        \ifnum\j>0
         \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\i-\jj);
        \fi
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to shade one cell, one can use the `backgrounds` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,font=\sffamily]
\pgfmathsetseed{42}
\foreach \i [evaluate={\ii=int(\i-1);}] in {0,...,5}{
    \foreach \j [evaluate={\jj=int(\j-1);}] in {0,...,9}{
        \node [shift={(\j,\i)},circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt] (n-\i-\j) at
        (rand*180:1/4+rnd/8){};
        \ifnum\i>0
         \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\ii-\j);
         \ifnum\j>0
          \node[draw,inner sep=1.5pt] (b-\i-\j) at 
            (barycentric cs:n-\i-\j=1,n-\ii-\j=1,n-\i-\jj=1,n-\ii-\jj=1){};
         \fi
       \fi
        \ifnum\j>0
         \draw [help lines] (n-\i-\j) -- (n-\i-\jj);
        \fi
}}
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \fill[gray!20] (n-3-5.center) -- (n-2-5.center) -- (n-2-4.center) --
 (n-3-4.center) -- cycle coordinate[pos=0.7] (aux);
\end{scope}
 \draw[<-] (b-3-5) --++ (1.5em,-0.3em) node[right]{cell center};
 \draw[<-] (aux) --++ (1em,2em) node[above right]{cell face};
 \draw[<-] (n-2-4) --++ (-1em,-1em) node[below left]{node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Something along the lines of the grid of the upper screen shot can be obtained with

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,font=\sffamily,
    bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt},
    declare function={a=0.5;},scale=2]
 \pgfmathsetseed{123}   
 \draw (0,0) node[bullet] (n-0-0) {} rectangle (5,4) node[bullet] (n-5-4) {}
  (0,4) node[bullet] (n-0-4) {}  (5,0) node[bullet] (n-5-0) {}
  foreach \X in {1,...,4}
  {({\X+a*(rnd-0.5)},0) node[bullet] (n-\X-0) {}
  ({\X+a*(rnd-0.5)},4) node[bullet] (n-\X-4) {}
  edge (n-\X-0)}
  foreach \Y in {1,...,3}
  {(0,{\Y+a*(rnd-0.5)}) node[bullet] (n-0-\Y) {}
  (5,{\Y+a*(rnd-0.5)}) node[bullet] (n-5-\Y) {}
  edge (n-0-\Y)}
  foreach \X [evaluate={\XX=int(\X-1)}] in {1,...,5} {
   foreach \Y [evaluate={\YY=int(\Y-1)}] in {1,...,4} {
   \ifnum\X<5
    \ifnum\Y<4
     (intersection of n-\X-0--n-\X-4 and  n-0-\Y--n-5-\Y) 
     node[bullet] (n-\X-\Y){}
    \fi 
   \fi
  (barycentric cs:n-\X-\Y=1,n-\XX-\Y=1,n-\X-\YY=1,n-\XX-\YY=1) 
  node[draw,inner sep=1.5pt] (b-\X-\Y){}
  }};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \fill[gray!20] (n-3-2.center) -- coordinate[pos=0.2] (aux) (n-2-2.center) --
  (n-2-1.center) -- (n-3-1.center) -- cycle ;
\end{scope}
\draw[<-] (b-3-2) --++ (1.6em,-0.3em) node[right]{cell center};
\draw[<-] (aux) --++ (0.3em,0.6em) node[above right]{cell face};
\draw[<-] (n-2-1) --++ (-0.3em,-0.3em) node[below left]{node};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. All the solutions work so well.