# Tikz Finite element help reproducing this triangulation

Tags: tikz-pgf

is there a way to easily reproduce finite element mesh with tikz? Without having to do them one by one for this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The answer to the question is yes. If you make the question more specific, your chances of getting a more specific answer will increase.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/260652 for a triangular grid with some randomness.

Comment: It's not the same length though

Comment: Well, neither do the edges in your hand-drawn sketch have the same lengths. They look a bit random, which is why I was digging out this post. As I wrote, making the question more specific would help.